# Apache loads one vhost faster than another

Tags: linux, apache, vhosts

I have 2 vhosts, I'm using Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7, with event MPM. I also use PHP-FPM with UNIX domain sockets, each PHP config has it's own socket file. The vhost configuration files are almost identical.

One website loads slower than the other, for example:

a simple "contact" page loads **1.19** seconds on the slow vhost, and **0.56** seconds on the fast vhost. What can be the root cause of this difference?

My server has 1 CPU core, and yet I see a total of 6 httpd processes, one of those is the parent and 5 workers. Is this normal or should there only be 1 worker process?

**EDIT:** I have tested with a simple html page (page.html) with just a few HTML lines, there is no PHP, so the PHP interpreter is not touched at all. And the problem persists. So PHP is not the problem.

**EDIT:** I am not using .htaccess files.

Here are my vhost configurations. First the slow vhost:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost PUBLIC-IP:443>
    ServerName www.domain1.tld
    ServerAlias domain1.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/domain1/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/hosts/domain1/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/hosts/domain1/logs/access_log combined env=!forwarded
    CustomLog /var/www/hosts/domain1/logs/access_log proxy env=forwarded
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tld/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tld/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tld/chain.pem

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        <If "-f %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm/domain1.tld.sock|fcgi://domain1.tld"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
    RewriteRule ^/page$ /page.php [L]
    ...
    ...
    a few rewrite rules
    ...

    <FilesMatch ".(js|css|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|woff|otf|ttf|svg)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "(\.js|\.css)$">
        RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" "^(.*)-gzip\"$" "$1\""
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/var/www/hosts/domain1/html">
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now the fast vhost:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost PUBLIC-IP:443>
    ServerName www.domain2.tld
    ServerAlias domain2.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/domain2/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/hosts/domain2/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/hosts/domain2/logs/access_log combined env=!forwarded
    CustomLog /var/www/hosts/domain2/logs/access_log proxy env=forwarded
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/chain.pem

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        <If "-f %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm/domain2.tld.sock|fcgi://domain2.tld"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
    RewriteRule ^/page$ /page.php [L]
    ...
    ...
    a few rewrite rules
    ...

    <FilesMatch ".(js|css|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|woff|otf|ttf|svg)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "(\.js|\.css)$">
        RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" "^(.*)-gzip\"$" "$1\""
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/var/www/hosts/domain2/html">
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are the applications running on each vhost identical, or even the same application?  Speed difference like that are more likely going to be due to things happening within the app, not with the web server.

Comment: Yes, they are identical. BTW, i just tested a simple HTML page, no PHP, so PHP process is not touched, result: same problem.. very strange..

Comment: Can you update your answer with your vhost definition?  Also any rules that may be set in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Added configs. I am not using .htaccess files.